# List with elements that were removed

Tags: python, list

I am a python programmer and I was using the remove function from a list. The problem is that it shows me the item that I am trying to remove. Here is the code that I wrote.

```
set1 = [10, 10, 10, 2, 4, 0]

for i in set1:
    if i < 9:
        set1.remove(i)
print(set1)
```

And this is the output

```
[10, 10, 10, 4]
```

Why does it show a 4? What can I do?

Comment: Try `set1 = set(i for i in set1 if i >=10)`

Comment: You should not modify a list as you are iterating through it. An alternative in this case would be using a list comprehension `set1 = [i for i in set1 if i >= 9]`